# QGLWidget get gl contextes for Windows

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I am using `QGLWidget and OpenCL.
To set the CL-GL interoperation I need

```
HGLRC glContext
HDC   deviceGLContext
```

How to get it using Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `QGLWidget` for current OpenGL operations with [`QGLWidget::makeCurrent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#makeCurrent) and then retrieve current `HGLRC` and `HDC` with [`wglGetCurrentContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`wglGetCurrentDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), respectively.